# Difference Between Eigenvalues of Schrödinger Operator with Different Boundary Conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators

Consider a Schrödinger operator
$$H=-\Delta+V$$
on a *nice* bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ (say, a ball or a cube), and assume for simplicity that $V$ is smooth.

Let $\lambda_D,\lambda_N$ and $\lambda_P$ denote the ground state eigenvalue of $H$ with Dirichlet, Neumann and periodic boundary conditions respectively. By using the variational characterization of the eigenvalues, it is sometimes possible to get trivial one-sided inequalities such as
$$\lambda_P\leq\lambda_D.$$
I'm interested in more detailed comparisons between these eigenvalues:

> **Question.** Does there exist results giving bounds on the distances
>   $$|\lambda_P-\lambda_D|,~|\lambda_N-\lambda_D|,~|\lambda_N-\lambda_P|,$$
>   probably depending on $\Omega$ and $V$?

My interest in this question stems from the following kind of problem:
Suppose we have an asymptotic result on the magnitude of $\lambda_D$ on the open ball $B(0,r)$ as $r\to\infty$. Is it sometimes possible to infer from this that $\lambda_N$ and $\lambda_P$ have the same asymptotic behavior?

Comment: this physics heuristics may be of some help: the sensitivity of an eigenvalue (energy level) to a change in boundary condition is called the "Thouless energy", it is given by the inverse of the time needed to propagate across the volume; Thouless compared this eigenvalue change $\Delta$ to the spacing $\delta$ between subsequent eigenvalues; if $\Delta<\delta$ the eigenfunctions are localized, if $\Delta>\delta$ the eigenfunctions are extended.

Comment: I think it might be worth an attempt to try to formulate a more specific question along these lines. In this generality, the min-max principle pretty much shows you what is going on (by the way, it of course also implies that $\lambda_N\le\lambda_D$ always). If you have negative potential sitting very close to the boundary, then $\lambda_N$ can take advantage of that while $\lambda_D$ can't ...

Comment: (cont'd) For example, in $d=1$, you can get a difference $\lambda_D-\lambda_N \simeq \|V\|_1^2$ in this way, for arbitrarily large $\Omega$.